# Oracle forms Multiple rows modification issue

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I m using forms 11g
I have one master-detail form.
I want to restrict the user from saving the non detail block record, If record entered in the corresponding master block has been rollbacked.

To be clear when i query or move out of that field i see a message 'do you want to save changes made?'
when i say 'NO', my master block values rolled back , but non detail block records are saving

I tried to use issue_rollback(null); but not working

Comment: Please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to describe your problem well.

Comment: I m using forms 11g
I have one master-detail form.
I want to restrict the user from saving the non detail block record, If record entered in the corresponding master block has been rollbacked.

to be clear when i query or move out of that field i see a message 'do you want to save changes made?'
when i say 'NO', my master block bvalues rolled back , but non detail block records are saving


I tried to use issue_rollback(null); but not working